# Crystal Report 13 prompts Database Login in VS 2010

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, odbc

I am currently having problem displaying the Crystal Report in my VB.Net(VS2010) application. I Googled this issue, found similar problem, but their solution didn't fixed mine.

Everytime I call the CR report from my VB application, it always prompts for a Database Login. I've entered my DB credentials but it fails. I am connecting to a MySQL5.1 via ODBC connector.

[image]

In my Crystal Report, I have created a custom Command which accept 2 parameters from my application, e.i, dateFrom and dateTo, which I used to query between the date range.

[image]

I've noticed that when I took off my code where it sets the Crystal Report parameter value, the Database Login doesn't appear.

Here's my code snippet:

```
Dim appPath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)
Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
Dim CRTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table
Dim CRTLI As CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo

cryRpt.Load(appPath & "\Reports\crDtrLogs.rpt")

frmReportViewer.crReportViewer.Refresh()
For Each CRTable In cryRpt.Database.Tables
   CRTLI = CRTable.LogOnInfo
   With CRTLI.ConnectionInfo
       .ServerName = "dtrsql"
       .UserID = "root"
       .Password = "root"
       .DatabaseName = "dtrsql"
   End With
   CRTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(CRTLI)
Next CRTable
```

When I took this out, everything works fine even without adding the table connection info

```
cryRpt.SetParameterValue("dtpFrom", dtpFrom.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
cryRpt.SetParameterValue("dtpTo", dtpTo.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))

cryRpt.SetParameterValue("strDateRange", dtpFrom.Value.Date.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy") & " - " & dtpTo.Value.Date.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy"))

frmReportViewer.crReportViewer.ReportSource = cryRpt
frmReportViewer.Show()
```

As always, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

eassy and simple solution for all ....
open field explorer---> database field --->Right Click -->current Data source --->reports connection----->report ----->property ----> set Property as---

Data Source: .\Databasename.accdb

and code on viewer form load as

Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument

```
  Dim Report1 As New rptItemWise

  Dim strServerName As String
  strServerName = Application.StartupPath
```

rptItemWise.SetDatabaseLogon("admin", "", strServerName, "dastabasename.accdb", True)

```
  cryRpt.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\rptItemWise.rpt")
```

also change the report connection same as data source i think that code work for you ..

Answer (score 0):

Check this code. I guess you should access to the database like this:

```
Dim appPath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)
Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument

Dim crtableLogoninfos As New TableLogOnInfos
Dim crtableLogoninfo As New TableLogOnInfo
Dim crConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo
Dim CrTables As Tables

cryRpt.Load(appPath & "\Reports\crDtrLogs.rpt")

crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "YOUR SERVER NAME"
crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "YOUR DATABASE NAME"
crConnectionInfo.UserID = "YOUR DATABASE USERNAME"
crConnectionInfo.Password = "YOUR DATABASE PASSWORD"

CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables

For Each CrTable In CrTables
    crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo
    crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo
    CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo)
Next CrTable
```